# Updating object array in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I do this:

```
var x = [
    { 'z': 3, y: [1,2,3,4]},
    { 'z': 5, y: [2,2,2,2]},
    { 'z': 6, y: [1,4,3,5]},
    { 'z': 8, y: [1,1,3,4]},
];

$(x).each(function() {
    console.log(this.z);
    $(this.y).each(function(i, n) {
       n = n * 2;
    });
});

// expected result from the first iteration would be: 
{ 'z': 3, y: [2,4,6,8]}
```

I want to update n, doesn't work though. Can it be done, and if so how?

Comment: It "works." It just doesn't do what you think it does, because `n` isn't a reference to what's in the original array.

Comment: fix the errors syntax first...

Comment: generally use `$.each(x,function(k,v){` when looping arrays or objects...no need to wrap in `$()`

Comment: Do you understand why you got so many downvotes on this question?  I wasn't one of them but I'm just checking to make sure for future posts n stuff...

Comment: Yeah, I phrased that terribly...

Comment: @Nathan - I think you got so many downvotes because your original example had some syntax errors in it. I personally thought they were minor, so I fixed them, but you should post valid code that conforms to these requirements: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

when you are doing `n = n * 2;` you are just updating the value of the local variable `n` in the `each` handler.

```
$(x).each(function (_, obj) {
    console.log(this.z);
    this.y = $.each(this.y, function (i, n) {
        obj.y[i] = n * 2;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cc45M/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(x).each(function() {
    console.log(this.z);
    var y = this.y;
    $(y).each(function(i, n) {
        y[i] *= 2;
    });
});
```